# Get the Last Logon Time for Each User Profile

Tags: powershell

I need to get the last logon time for each user profile on a remote computer (not the local accounts). I've tried something similar to the following using Win32_UserProfile & LastLogonTime, however this is not giving accurate results. For example, one this computer, only 1 account has been used in the past year, however LastUpdateTime is showing very recent dates. Some accounts have not even been logged into and should say "N/A", but it doesn't.

```
 $RemoteSB_UserADID = Get-WmiObject win32_userprofile -Property * | Where-Object {$_.LocalPath -like "*users*"} | Sort-Object $_.LastUseTime | ForEach-Object{
     $Parts = $_.LocalPath.Split("\")
     $ADID = $Parts[$Parts.Length - 1]
                        
     if ($ADID -ne "SPECIALPURPOSEACCOUNT1" -and $ADID -ne "SPECIALPURPOSEACCOUNT2"){
         $Time = $null
         try{
             $Time = $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime)
         }catch{
             $Time = "N/A"
         }
                            
         "[$ADID | $Time]"
     }
}
```

**Example Output**

> [Acct1 | 03/13/2022 07:18:19]
> [Acct2 | 03/15/202214:59:16]
> [Acct3 | 03/13/2022 07:18:19]
> [Acct4 | 03/16/2022 11:53:17] <--- only "active" account

How can I go about retrieving accurate (or decently accurate) login times for each user profile? Thanks!

Comment: Would recommend this: https://adamtheautomator.com/user-logon-event-id/.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - Please summarize/synopsize the information at that link, and post it as an answer (including the link); it is generally discouraged to answer a question in the comments. (Even if I do it myself every so often...)

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know for what reason you need that, so that I know how to find a (better) solution for you.

If you need to cleanup your profiles not used for a long time at the target system, then take the last changed date of "ntuser.dat". That is the last logon if you define logon like logging on to a new session. If the user was logged on and simply locked the computer or used standby and then relogs then this date won't change.

Use this to get this date from all users you have access to but possibly not getting real user names

```
Get-ChildItem \\REMOTECOMPUTERNAMEHERE\Users\*\ntuser.dat -Attributes Hidden,Archive | Select @{Name="NameByFolder";Expression={($_.DirectoryName -split "\\")[-1]}},LastWriteTime
```

Or this a bit more complex version

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName REMOTECOMPUTERNAMEHERE -ScriptBlock {$UsersWithProfilePath = @{}
dir "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" |
where {$_.name -like "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-*"} |
foreach {$UsersWithProfilePath[([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]$_.name.split("\")[-1]).Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value] = $_.GetValue("ProfileImagePath")}
foreach ($Name in $UsersWithProfilePath.Keys) {@{$Name =(dir (join-path $UsersWithProfilePath.$Name ntuser.dat) -Attributes Hidden,Archive,System).LastWriteTime}}}
```

Depending on what you need you need to change it a bit.
Sorry for the long codelines... it is late here.